# Issue Rewriting Backpropagation Network to Use Keras

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to rewrite my code from `neuralnet` to use Keras, but I'm having issues getting the same results (R/Rstudio) :(.

My code first creates an array of dimensions `c(n, nvar, ndata)`  where `n = # observations`, `nvar = # inputs+1`, and `ndata = # simulations`. e.g., for simplicity, `c(500,3,500)` creates `500` matrices of dim `3x500,` filled with `0`. next, i fill each matrix in the array with a random binomial distribution of `0` and `1`. for example, the matrix looks like this, with the columns labeled `x1, x2, y` where `x1` and `x2` are the inputs and `y` is the output/label.

The details of this part aren't really important -- the result is a matrix that looks like the following, which is fed into my neural network.

[image: 1]

The neural network is a backpropagation with a structure of (for example) inputs `x1,x2` `1` hidden layer of `5` hidden units, and then an output layer. the way I write this using `neuralnet` is as follows:

```
 nnet <- neuralnet(y~x1+x2, currentmatrix, hidden=5, stepmax = 10^7,err.fct = "ce",linear.output = F,likelihood = T)
  
  predictions <- predict(nnet,currentmatrix[,1:nvar-1])
```

Where `currentmatrix` is the selected matrix in the array. I enclose the network in a `for loop` of `ndata=500` iterations -- so each matrix in the array is fitted once and the predictions (and resulting calculations) stored.

Now I'm trying to write this in Keras/tf and my code is as follows:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "sigmoid", input_shape = c(2)) %>% #logistic, input
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid") #output

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

for(i in 1:ndata){
... #select matrix

  currentmatrix <- datas[,,i]
  
  trainee <- currentmatrix[,-3]
  trainee <- as.matrix(array_reshape(trainee, c(500,2)))

  y1 <- y
  dim(y1) <- c(500,1)
  
  history <- model %>% fit(
    trainee,
    y1,
    epochs = 2,
    batch_size = 50,
  )
  
  predictions <- model %>% predict(currentmatrix[,1:nvar-1])
}
```

But for some reason this isn't returning the same results as my `neuralnet` code and I'm not sure why. I think it has to do with either how I'm creating/fitting the model, or how I'm inputting the data into the Keras model. Can anyone help? I'd be happy to post my full code :)).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the two models have different architecture.  `nnet` model has a single hidden layer of size 5, while `keras` one has two hidden layers with size 2 and 10.  Besides that, deep learning algorithms contain randomness (e.g. weight initialization), so the results are not exactly reproducible (unless you control the random seed very carefully).

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the hidden layer issue! I am using a seed which I didn't include in the code, but I think the issue is deeper. After I take the predictions I calculate their variance and deviance over the course of the 500 simulations, and the variance should always be near twice the deviance -- at least it is so with the neuralnet code. Could it have something to do with the choice of optimizer/loss/epoch/batch-size? Thanks again :)